# Obj-C & Cocoa: Variable is nil after applicationDidFinishLaunching:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In the interface for my AppDelegate I have the following property declaration:

```
@property (strong) NSArray *fileNamesInCurrentDirectory;
```

and then, in the implementation:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self setFileNamesInCurrentDirectory:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"hello"]];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [self.fileNamesInCurrentDirectory count];
}
```

When `numberOfRowsInTableView` is called, `fileNamesInCurrentDirectory` is `nil`. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you move the initialization to `applicationWillFinishLaunching:`?

Comment: What difference would it make whether he moves this code to another method?

Comment: Have you separately implemented `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`? That's the replacement for `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` that Xcode will put into new projects by default and my guess is that `UIApplication` will call the new in preference to the old.

Comment: @Tommy He's using Cocoa on the Mac, not Cocoa Touch in iOS.  The methods are different.

Comment: @Leonnears `applicationWillFinishLaunching:` is sent earlier than `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` - perhaps earlier than `numberOfRowsInTableView:`.

Comment: @robmayoff you're absolutely right, and if I'd spent even a moment looking at the `NSNotification` or `NSTableView` references I wouldn't have made such a stupid error. Apologies all round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

> Sent by the default notification center after the application has been launched and initialized

Which means, I guess, that the application loads entirely, build all views and then call the method.

Is there any reason why you need your method call to occur after the application is loaded ?

Comment: Nope, none whatsoever. So where should I do this sort of initialisation? In the init method, applicationWillFinishLaunching: ...?

Comment: Well for starters it looks weird to me that your `AppDelegate` is a `UITableViewDataSource`. The delegate's purpose is to handle events from 'the outside' such as background-foreground transition (there are other examples). If it were me, I'd have a `UIViewController` being the data source. This view controller would do all necessary work in its `init` method and then load & display the tableview. The application delegate would only need to load & display the view controller if not done automatically by storyboard.

Comment: Thanks. I've got a lot to learn! I'll go and read up on this stuff now.

Comment: @Olotiar `UITableViewDataSource` and `UIViewController` are part of Cocoa Touch, but based on the question's tags and example code, Matt H seems to be using Cocoa (on OS X), not Cocoa Touch.

Comment: @MattH a kneejerk reaction might be to call `reloadData` immediately after you call `setFileNamesInCurrentDirectory:`; if that solves the problem then this diagnosis is correct. The most appropriate thing might be not to use your delegate as a data source regardless of whether you're in OS X or iOS — the data source can set itself up appropriate in its init before it is notified to the table view.

Comment: @robmayoff This is very true, I obviously meant their NS counterparts.

Comment: Call `reload` on the table view in your did finish launching

Answer (score 2):

It's not said that `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is called before `numberOfRowsInTableView`.

The first method to be called is the `init` method, then `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Use the `init` method to initialize all your variables, expect for those variables that are in the xib file so they're not already loaded. The outlets loaded from the xib can be initialized in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` (or `awakeFromNib`).

Answer (score 2):

It is as Ramy Al Zuhouri said, it's a matter of timing. Here are some of the methods that can be used at start up, so you can see the order that they execute:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init])
        NSLog(@"In init");
    return self;
}

+(void)initialize {
    NSLog(@"Initialize");
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    NSLog(@"awakeFromNib");
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"applicationDidFinishLaunching");
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInTableView");
    return [self.fileNamesInCurrentDirectory count];
}
```

The log shows this:

```
2012-11-12 14:23:56.880 TableViewTimingProblem[1399:303] Initialize
2012-11-12 14:23:56.881 TableViewTimingProblem[1399:303] In init
2012-11-12 14:23:56.885 TableViewTimingProblem[1399:303] awakeFromNib
2012-11-12 14:23:56.893 TableViewTimingProblem[1399:303] numberOfRowsInTableView
2012-11-12 14:23:56.937 TableViewTimingProblem[1399:303] applicationDidFinishLaunching
```

Comment: So, completing the thought;   call `reload` on the table view from `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` and OP's code should work.